# manipulating the input field based upon the success call

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
<div id="email-forgot-div">
    <input data-placement="bottom" type="text" class="form-control form-control-email" id="Forgot-Email" name="Forgot-Email">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="reg-forgot-submit">Submit</button>
    <div id="ajaxNotify"></div>
</div>
```

So after my success call, I am trying to add field after the `forgot-email`, I want to also resize both the fields to half of the size, right now the size is one field is full size and it has a submit `button` on line.

Now I want to show two fields and submit `button` on same one line. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add "Float categories" for example:

```
<input style="float:left;" /><button style="float:right;"></button>
```

That's the only way I can think of, if there is other available methods.  Try those instead.  I used the floats to move my logo apart from my header's words in the same line on my header.  Also have you considered CSS for "Liquid" (percentage width) to see if that may help any?  Also look into maxlength (length of allowed characters) size controls how much characters are visible until you type more.  However I don't believe the maxlength applies to buttons, but give it a try anyway.

```
<input size="30" maxlength="100" /><button size="15"></button>
```

Hope this works!

Answer (score 0):

In most situations it's going to be easier to have the extra input on the page, and show/hide it when the form is submitted. I've done a simple plunk [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/e7RyzkOjlpEZx1fvwONs/preview) - it adds a class to #email-forgot-div when the submit button is clicked. This additional class shows the extra input and changes the width of the form elements.

The modified html is:

```
<div id="email-forgot-div">
  <input data-placement="bottom" type="text" class="form-control form-control-email" id="Forgot-Email" name="Forgot-Email" />
  <input class="form-control extra" name="extra"/> 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="reg-forgot-submit">Submit</button>
  <div id="ajaxNotify"></div>
</div>
```

The javascript to bind the class change on button click is:

```
$('#reg-forgot-submit').on('click', function() {
  $('#email-forgot-div').addClass('extra-input');
  return false;
});
```

And the relevant css is:

```
#email-forgot-div input, #email-forgot-div button {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.extra {
  display: none;
}

#email-forgot-div.extra-input input, #email-forgot-div.extra-input button {
  display: block;
  width: 33.333%;
}
```

Comment: Link-only answers are generally not recommended due to potential link rot.  Can you update your answer to provide a small code example?